# How to call base name of files from a specific path in python?

Tags: python, path, filenames, glob

I have many files in a specific path such :`/a/b/c/*.tif`. I wnat to get their basenames as a list.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

pattern = '/a/b/c/*.tif'
filenames = [path.basename(x) for x in glob(pattern)]
pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp(f[:9]) for f in filenames])
```

This code has `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call the function [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) instead of using the module name `glob` in your first list comprehension, which led to the `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Also you should import the os module to do [os.path.basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

pattern = '/a/b/c/*.tif'
#Use glob.glob to call the function
filenames = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(pattern)]
pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp(f[:9]) for f in filenames])
```

Comment: Hi @Devesh Kumar Singh ,There is `NameError: name 'path' is not defined` error with your answer.

Comment: Is that `os.path`  @nickan ? If yes I have fixed the code for the same, please have a look